# generate random numbers without repetition - java

Tags: java, random

i'm writing a program for a complicated mathematical operation. I read numbers from a file, then use these numbers to generate as many as possible of sets of 10 random numbers whose sum is 590 and has 5 even numbers and 5 odd numbers (the sum and number of odd and even is changeable).
every time I run the code, I get either repeated sets or repeated numbers withing the set.

how to fix this so I have unique sets with 10 unique numbers?

here is my code:

```
 public static void main(String args[])
  {
     List<Long> numbers = new ArrayList<Long>();
  try{
  FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("numbers.txt");
  DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
  String strLine;
  while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
      numbers.add(Long.valueOf(strLine));
  }
  Long[] selectedNumbers = new Long[10];
  Random r = new Random();
  for (int j =0; j<100000; j++){
      long sum = 0;
      int odd = 0;
      int even = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i < selectedNumbers.length; i++){
          selectedNumbers[i] = numbers.get(r.nextInt(numbers.size()));
          if (selectedNumbers[i] % 2 == 0)
          {
              even++;
          } 
          else
          {
              odd++;
          }
          sum = sum + selectedNumbers[i];         
      }

          if (even == 5 && sum == 590 )
          {
              for(int k = 0; k < selectedNumbers.length; k++)
              {
                  System.out.print(selectedNumbers[k] + "\t");
              }
              System.out.print("\n");
          }



  }
  in.close();
    }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
  System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
  }
  }
```

Comment: Is this a homework exercise?

Comment: With every number you make, to make sure it's not a repeat makes the time complexity `O(n^2)`

Comment: @ SK9, this is not homework, I'm doing analytical probabilities on some of my own data.

Comment: @ Cole Johnson, how to approach this, you mean I should have only 2 nested loops? the first loop (with i upto 100,000) is mandatory, what would be the other loop?

Comment: Please read my answer.  Your code is **not** doing what you describe.  Is it even **your** code?

Comment: I read numbers from a file, add them to a list, then creat array of length 10, then randomly add numbers to the array, then count the even, odd and the sum, then apply the condition of sum and even. this is my understanding of how to produce sets with 10 numbers satisfying the conditions

Comment: OK. So, the numbers in your array are **not** random, they are just randomly selected from the values read from your file.  Now, what is your question/problem?  What works not as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout SecureRandom on [this](http://www.javaexchange.com) site. It complies with FIPS140-2 or at least did. I've used it to generate "random" 128-bit GUIDs to use as a database ID and I can say for certain that in tests I've inserted around 50 million records into a database and never once hit the same number.

Answer (score 0):

system-time + randomNumber can make sure your number not repeat!

Comment: this would fix the repetition within a set (inner loop), but how to make sure there is no repetition happens after each iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: Umm. Not necessarily. Look at this system time: 1813. Then a random number is generated, say 5. Total is 1818. Now the system time is 1814. Then a random number is generated, say 4. Total is 1818. :(

Answer (score 0):

You are working with the **same** array that you read in at the beginning and use random index values to pick it's elements.

This is not what your post states:

> ... to generate as many as possible of sets of 10 random numbers whose
>   sum is 590 and has 5 even numbers and 5 odd numbers ...

Again, your 10 (or whatever number you actually enter) values are not picked at random.  Only their order would differ.  And, yes, if you pick 10 random integers from 0 to 10 ten times, you *could* get the same numbers several times.

Comment: it is my code and I'm still a beginner in Java, this is why I'm here.

Comment: OK. Then why it's doing things that are completely different from your description? Is your description correct?  I'm not saying that you made mistakes, but that your entire code is written to solve a different problem.